# how to do a switch statement in laravel fortify redirect after login

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-fortify

how do i do a switch statement with

`
``

```
public function toResponse($request){return $request->wantsJson()
```

```
                ? response()->json(['two_factor' => false])

                : redirect()->intended(

                    auth()->user()->is_admin ? route('admin.dashboard') : route('dashboard')

                    auth()->user()->is_admin ? route('admin.dashboard') :route('dashboard'),
                                          
                    auth()->user()->is_Hr ? route('hr.dashboard') : route('dashboard'),

                    auth()->user()->is_clack ? route('clack.dashboard') : route('dashboard'),

                    auth()->user()->is_worker  ? route('workes.dashboard') : route('dashboard'),
                );
}`
```

```
``
```

want to redirect to each roles dashoard after login

redirect after login based on roles

Comment: Hello, its not clear what your question is?  What have you tried to do and what problem are you having?  Please provide more info in your question.

Comment: This is not possible in this way. `auth()->user()` will be null if the user is not signed in. Instead you probably should redirect back to the same route that has this switch after you log in and at that point the user will not be null anymore and will redirect, but you can't really use `intended` for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new method or use a variable to get the intended route, you can't use how you added it.

Following should help you, **Make sure user is loggedin at this point**

```php
public function toResponse($request) {
    return $request->wantsJson() ? 
        response()->json(['two_factor' => false]) : 
        redirect()->intended($this->getIntendedRoute());
}

public function getIntendedRoute() {
    return match(true) {
        auth()->user()->is_admin => route('admin.dashboard'),
        auth()->user()->is_Hr => route('hr.dashboard'),
        auth()->user()->is_clack => route('clack.dashboard'),
        auth()->user()->is_worker => route('workes.dashboard'),
        default => route('dashboard'),
    };

};
}
```

This code first checks each condition and returns the corresponding route if a match is found, and if none of the conditions match, it falls back to the default case and returns the route for the dashboard.

Comment: i don't know if is my route that is the problem it keep redirecting me back to default even

Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth','auth.isAdmin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [AdminDashboardController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('admin.dashboard');
});